# NSURLConnection http PUT with HTTP_RANGE not working

Tags: iphone, http, httpwebrequest, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am trying to upload an image in chunks to the server from iphone, I have PHP code on the server side which reads the data and appends using HTTP_RANGE to an existing image.

Note : server side code is tested and running fine using html from browser.

My server side code only take POST as httpMethod, so I have to give restMethod = PUT and HTTP_RANGE in the body of the post, like this :-

```
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n\r\n--%@\r\n", kHttpPostMimeBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"restMethod\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"PUT"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", kHttpPostMimeBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"HTTP_RANGE\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-0",offset] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The uploaded image is 0KB. I have also tried sending the file in one chunk only with restMethod = PUT and HTTP_RANGE=0-0, it still is 0KB, but if I only do restMethod = PUT and omit out HTTP_RANGE the image is uploaded successfully.

I am really stumped here, please help !!

EDIT :: Adding the actual HTTP Request :-

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",
                             kHttpPostMimeBoundary];

[req addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];      

[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *bodyData = [NSMutableData data];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n\r\n--%@\r\n", kHttpPostMimeBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"restMethod\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"PUT"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  

if (offset > 0) {
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", kHttpPostMimeBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"HTTP_RANGE\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-0",offset] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  

}
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", kHttpPostMimeBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n",mimeType]
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:fileData];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",kHttpPostMimeBoundary]
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [bodyData length]];
[headerParamDict setValue:msgLength forKey:@"Content-Length"];

[req setHTTPBody: bodyData];
```

Comment: Can you show the actual HTTP request that you're generating?

Comment: Hi Seamus, please see my post again, I have added the HTTP request.